# GCC Compiler Error Again

Tags: c

I was once again trying to install a compiler onto my SGI Indy computer running Irix version 6.5, and this time, I found a file that has all of the libraries I thought I would have needed. When I compiled, I get an error that says

```
cc1: rld: Fatal Error: Cannot Successfully map soname 'libmpc.so.4' under any of the filenames /opt/local/gcc473/lib/libmpc.so.4:/usr/lib32/libmpcso.4
```

It says some more directories, which I will show in this photo:
[image]

I installed the compiler that was pre-installed from [here](http://forums.irix.cc/thread-207.html)

I also had install it to another drive that did not have the Irix OS installed on it so I would have enough space, so there are no /usr or /etc directories inside.

Thanks for your assistance,
-rjhwinner03

Comment: I have to go to bed, but I will improve the image quality tomorrow.

Comment: This question is on-topic on [retrocomputing.se], but I think it'd do better on [unix.se] because it's a problem that isn't specific to Irix (at least, I don't think it is). You'll have to join that community before you can post comments or edit the question. I recommend reading the [tour], too.

Comment: I am rather new to using Unix machines, so I may be in quite the pickle

Comment: That looks like a pretty standard "missing library" error to me, but I don't know enough to place it.

Comment: Well, you may be right, because the library is not included in any of the file folders that it is talking about, so I may just move the files into all of the folders that it mentions.

Comment: That's probably not **The Correct Solution** but it'll probably work. Let me know if it does so I can post it as an answer! (Unless you want to post it as an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

you said "installing compiler" which i assume you are not building it from source.
my recommendation would be to **build from source**:

download gcc source tarball from a gnu.gcc.org mirror site.  You will download something like `gcc-4.9.4.tar.gz` or `gcc-4.9.4.tar.bz2`.  Get all the versions you need...

Important: if for example your IRIX 6.5 has gcc-3.2.3, then get and start with gcc-3.4.6 which is the last version of gcc-3.  And once built then use that to build the last gcc-4.x.x version; then use that to build the last version of gcc-5.x.x and so on.

The big 3 dependencies GCC uses is

- `gmp` the GNU multiple precision arithmetic library:  https://gmplib.org/
- `mpfr` https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-3.1.6/
- `mpc` http://www.multiprecision.org/mpc/download.html

build gmp first since everything else is dependent on that, then build mpfr-3.1.6; then mpc-1.0.3 which is the one you are missing.  *Don' get mpfr-4.x you won't need it on IRIX, it's too new and will likely give you problems.*

for any, do `./configure --help` to see a list of build options, prior to doing

- ./configure
- ./make
- ./make check
- ./make install

**example:**

```
tar -xf gmp-6.1.2.tar.bz2
cd gmp-6.1.2/
./configure --help
./configure --prefix=/opt/gmp-6.1.2
./make
./make check
./make install

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gmp-6.1.2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
tar -xf mpfr-3.1.6.tar.gz 
cd mpfr-3.1.6/
./configure --help
./configure --prefix=/opt/mpfr-3.1.6 --with-gmp=/opt/gmp-6.1.2
./make
./make check
./make install

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mpfr-3.1.6/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
tar -xf mpc-1.1.0.tar.gz
cd mpc-1.1.0/
./configure --help
./configure --prefix=/opt/mpc-1.1.0 --with-gmp=/opt/gmp-6.1.2 --with-mpfr=/opt/mpfr-3.1.6
./make
./make check
./make install

for each gcc-#.x.x do the same process, using

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gmp-6.1.2/lib:/opt/mpfr-3.1.2/lib:/opt/mpc-1.1.0/lib

./configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-#.x.x --with-gmp=/opt/gmp-6.1.2 --with-mpfr=/opt/mpfr-3.1.6 --with-mpc=/opt/mpc-1.1.0
./make
./make check
./make install

then be sure to set

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc-#.x.x/lib64:/opt/gcc-#.x.x/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
PATH=/opt/gcc-#.x.x/bin:$PATH

before building the next version of gcc.
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html or https://www.gnu.org/prep/ftp.html then choose closest then look under releases for the gcc tarball.

*mpc might be more linux than irix, which is why you don't have it.*

Comment: I got the files from that website that is posted in the original question. Don't let my profile picture fool you, because I do not really know Unix...

Comment: This is very long and complicated, do you know how I could install the MIPSpro compiler from ftp.irix.cc?

Comment: maybe... developmentlibraries.tar.gz;  my IRIX memory is not that great other than I remember disposing of octanes; the mipspro compiler was SGI's version of the C/C++ compiler of that era.  Like any, it has dependencies and you need to need to have those dependencies installed in order to install subsequent software packages that rely on them.

Comment: there used to be a freeware sgi website that had a lot of dependency packages like what you may need, but that was for than 5 years ago when I messed with or needed to remotely care about anything IRIX, sorry.  But i remember many issues like this when needing some software package running in to many dependency problems, and from experience/memory if you are not running irix 6.5.28 or 6.5.30 then you likely need to update to that.  Then you need the `mpc` library which provides `libmpc.so`.  *The libmp.so.4 may then be another issue, as opposed to libmpc.so.1 for example.

Comment: look for `mpc` in foundation1.tar.gz, foundation2.tar.gz, or developmentlibraries.tar.gz.

Comment: Already used foundation 1 and 2, but I will try developmentlibraries

Comment: I used the DINA netboot appliance with pre-added discs. These included Foundation1, Foundation2, and the rest of the disks needed to get a basic installation, which does not include any demos or MIPSpro, or pretty much anything else except a cool installation.